# MATLAB profiler. DetailLevel: mmex?

Tags: matlab

In the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/profile.html) I see the following :

[image]
My question is: What is `DetailLevel` for ? What does the default value `mmex` mean? I couldn't find an explanation of these keywords on the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for an old feature of the profiler, which is now undocumented. The `DetailLevel` property controls which functions are profiled; if it is `'mmex'` then M-functions, subfunctions and MEX-functions will be profiled, while if it is `'builtin'`, builtins will be profiled as well.

There used to be a third level, `'operator'`, which would even profile things like `+`.

Comment: Is it possible to turn off the profiling for mex functions due to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323117/matlabs-run-and-time-crashes-with-mex-file?noredirect=1#comment77608045_45323117)?