# Matlab's 'run and time' crashes with mex file

Tags: matlab, mex

I am using [glmnet](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet_matlab/) library within my codebase in Matlab without problems during normal operation. However the moment I use Matlab's 'run and time' feature to analyse performance of my codebase, Matlab throws an access violation. The Mex file is the one that is shipped with the package.

Is there a fundamental incompatibility of mex files and 'run and time', or do Mex files have to be strictly written to conform to 'run and time' runtime standards (perhaps to do with memory allocation/deallocation)?

I don't want to start digging around in the third party code - all I want is for the profiler to tell me how long was spent executing the mex file in the context of my codebase - I am not interested in what is going on in the mex file. Is there a way to configure the profiler to deal with the mex file in this way?

The stack trace is as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Access violation detected at Wed Jul 26 10:10:39 2017
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Default Encoding    : windows-1252
  Deployed            : false
  Graphics card 1     : Intel Corporation ( 0x8086 ) Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics 640 Version 21.20.16.4664
  Host Name           : DESKTOP-MARUMC2
  MATLAB Architecture : win64
  MATLAB Entitlement ID: 1208320
  MATLAB Root         : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b
  MATLAB Version      : 9.1.0.441655 (R2016b)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Microsoft Windows 10 Home
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : Version 10.0 (Build 14393)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Access violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 00000000fc615760  RDX = 00000000043f8d10
  RSP = 00000000043f7128  RBP = 00000000043f8d10
  RSI = 00000000aaf4ba00  RDI = 0000000000000000

   R8 = 00000000043f7f30   R9 = 00000000fc615760
  R10 = 0000000000000000  R11 = 00000000043f8d10
  R12 = 0000000000000001  R13 = 0000000000000000
  R14 = 00000000043f8d10  R15 = 00000000fc615760

  RIP = 000000018008346f  EFL = 00010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x000000018008346f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\win64\libmx.dll+00537711 MXGETPR+00000003
[  1] 0x00007ffb629619dc C:\Users\work\glmnet_matlab\glmnetMex.mexw64+00006620 MEXFUNCTION+00002524
```

Comment: Never happened to me, so its not "run and time" and "mex", but just something specific in the mex that is making this crash.

Comment: I see there is a detail level for the profiler as desribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401393/matlab-profiler-detaillevel-mmex), however it looks like you cannot exclude mex files...

Comment: Do you need to profile the whole code? You could always try to profile the mex by `tic/toc`

Comment: Yes, I currently do this, but I am unsure about the overhead of tic/toc - the function in question is used 10,000s of times.

Comment: Id the overheard of tic/toc is a problem, then your fucntion is so fast that you can not optimize it!

Comment: I don't want to optimise the function, I want to find out how much time is spent in the function - the function for example is one of many ways to solve the Lasso regression problem - I want to test several ways (functions) to see which one is fastest.

Comment: The function is called 100,000s of times, which adds up to a significant proportion of execution time. Adding tic toc in this high frequency case would be detrimental due to its cost. So it is not the one time execution cost of the function, but its cumulative cost that I am interested in.

Comment: Run it once and multiply by 100.000?

Comment: Throughout the algorithm, this function's execution time will be drawn from some unknown distribution that may not be stationary as the algorithm progresses. I just want to know the proportion of the algorithm time spent in this function.